# Can't pass a value from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is wrong:

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
    $a = 14;
    $.ajax({
        url  : 'msg.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : {a:$a}
    });
    window.location = 'msg.php';
});
```

`msg.php` contains:

```
var_dump($_POST['a']); // NULL, but expected: 14
```

Comment: Why that `window.location`? That would reload the page _before_ the ajax call completes.

Comment: Changing the window.location will cause the page to reload but not post the value in 'a'.  Instead you want to add a 'success' function to your ajax call to get the response and then put that into your page.

Comment: Variables in Javascript need not start with `$`.

Comment: Comment out the `window.location` line. If you wish to redirect to the page then do a form submit. Read up on making AJAX calls using [jQuery.ajax](api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @srvikram13,   Five answers but I still cannot get value of `a` insisde `msg.php`. `var_dump($_POST['a']);` is still `NULL`.

Comment: 5 Answers and no thanks!  Still, if you've not got your answer then I can *almost* understand that.  If you have tried a 'success' or 'done' style version, can you update your question to include *exactly* what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
    var a = 14;
    $.ajax({
       url  : 'msg.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : {a:a},
       complete: function (data) {
           console.log( data ); // this will tell you the output of var_dump.
           window.location.href = 'msg.php';
       }
    });
    // window.location = 'msg.php';
});
```

also this line `window.location.href = 'msg.php';` in function `complete` will actually redirect you to the msg.php, so if you dont want any redirects remove those lines..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
        var  a = 14;//not $a since this is javascript
        $.ajax({
         url  : 'msg.php',
         type : 'post',
         data : {'a':a}
    });
    window.location = 'msg.php';
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't change much - `$a` is still a valid name for a variable in js.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#click01').click(function(){
    var a = 14
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "msg.php",
           data: {a:a},
           beforeSend: function () {
           // do action
           },
           success: function(html){
                window.location = 'msg.php';        
           }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set the `window.location` you want to set a 'success' function on the ajax call so that when it finishes it takes the response and puts it into your page.

E.g. something like:

```
 $('#click01').click(function(){
        $a = 14;
        $.ajax({
         url  : 'msg.php',
         type : 'post',
         data : {a:$a},
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           $('#placeToPutTheResponse').append( data );
         }
    });
  });
```

The above assumes that you have added an HTML node with the id="placeToPutTheResponse"

It is worth reading this other post on SO for a decent overview:  [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

It uses `done` rather than success, and slightly different syntax, but it's a great overview.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#click01',function () {
    var a = 14;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'msg.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {a: a},
        success: function(e){
            console.log(e);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```